# Derivative of logarithm of loss function. Logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, loss-function

I am reading machine learning literature. I found the log-loss function of logistic regression algorithm:
$$
l(w) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\ln(1+e^{-y_nw^Tx_n})
$$
Where $ y \in {-1;1}, w \in R^P, x_n \in R^P$
Usually I don't have any problem with taking derivatives. Think that derivatives w.r.t. to a vector is something new to me.
I can't figure out on how to take derivative w.r.t w. My try was:
$$
\frac{dl(w)}{dw}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{e^{-y_nw^Tx_n}y_nx_n}{1+e^{-y_nw^Tx_N}}
$$
Is it possible that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
... \\
\frac{dl(w)}{w_i} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{-e^{-y_nw^Tx_n}y_nx_n}{1+e^{-y_nw^Tx_n}}x_i  \\
...\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I suspect that here is something wrong. Can you please show me some example, some hints on how to do that.
Thanx

Comment: It is probably derivative with respect to components. Where did you get it from?

Comment: It is my homework of ML. So it is basically not a task from home work, but task is connected with that. Teacher sayed that the derivative of that was shown in the lecture, but it was not. So I am trying to get it by myself